# Pgk.add("PyPlot") fails; "package ZMQ has no versions". macOS 10.15.7

Tags: matplotlib, zeromq

I am trying to install PyPlot, on macOS 10.15.7 with Anaconda installed and up-to-date. Whether I do it in command line julia or with IJulia in a Jupyter notebook within JupyterLab,

```
Pkg.add("PyPlot")
```

gives:

```
Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package ZMQ [c2297ded]:
 ZMQ [c2297ded] log:
 ├─ZMQ [c2297ded] has no known versions!
 └─found to have no compatible versions left with IJulia [7073ff75]
```

Likewise with

```
Pkg.add("PyCall")
```

Comment: Pyplot is part of Matplotlib. Try installing Matplotlib.

Comment: I missed an important detail in the keywords: this is the PyPlot package of Julia. I have Python with matplotlib etc. via Anaconda, and in fact Julia has ZMQ version 1.2.1, yet  attempt to install the Julia package PyPlot gags on ZMQ as noted above.